# Checking if audio is playing with bash script on Tasker

Tags: tasker, bash

I have the small script below to check if audio is in use on my Android.

```
if grep -q RUNNING /proc/asound/card*/pcm*/sub*/status; then echo "Playing" ; else echo "Idle"; fi
```

It works nicely in the console. However, if I execute it in Tasker it always returns "Playing" which means it always evaluates to true.

Anybody an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Welcome to [android.se]. I modified the title to make it more general, in case there's alternative to your script.

Comment: Try this approach in your script and let me know the results: The system service `media.player` would show you what file(s) is/are being played under Android. Use it as a condition.  Access the dump of the system using `dumpsys media.player`. Surprisingly, when I try your script in my device, it always ends up with "Idle".

Comment: I get an unknown error code when i call that in console no matter if root or not. I am on cyanogenmod 13 if this helps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because OP is running CM13 (CM has not released any stable build of Marshmallow so far) which currently has nightly or experiment builds. As such, this question isn't in consonance with the consensus we've [here](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/recommendation-for-questions-pertaining-to-a-problem-specific-to-a-nightly-build?)

Comment: But the shellscript works in console. It only goes somehow wrong when run in tasker. And that problem seems to be very similar for other people as well as you wrote. I do not think that this is related to cm13 but rather tasker itself.

Comment: When you say console, do you mean a terminal emulator app running in Android or adb?

Comment: I mean a terminal emulator.